# How to make random words

Tags: java

I am making a Java type teacher(to teach typing). I need to generate random words that will be given to type. I made a program to generate random words but it generates just random words without any meaning, but I want to generate real words.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Generator {

    private String CHAR_LIST = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    private int No_Of_Chars = 2;

    public Generator(String CHARS, int No_Of_Char) {
        No_Of_Chars = No_Of_Char;
        CHAR_LIST = CHARS;
    }

    public String RandomString() {

        String randStr = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < No_Of_Chars; i++) {
            int number = getRandomNumber();
            char ch = CHAR_LIST.charAt(number);
            randStr = randStr + ch;

        }

        return randStr;
    }

    private int getRandomNumber() {

        int randomInt = 0;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(CHAR_LIST.length());

        if (randomInt - 1 == -1) {
            return randomInt;
        } else {
            return randomInt - 1;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: We can't see your program.

Comment: You have a few options, but I think you should have a list of real words and randomly select from that list.

Comment: Find/create a list of dictionary words and draw from that.

Comment: You're going to need some kind of dictionary to bounce those random words off.  Instead, I'd create a table with a couple hundred words and write code to randomly pick them one at a time.

Comment: But I never want to a word twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other said get a dictionary.
Ask your browser for a word list site. I found this one at the first search : http://www.md5this.com/tools/wordlists.html

Load the file in an ArrayList, a word by element.

Get a random index by `int idx = new Random().nextInt(yourArray.size());`.

Return the word at that index and remove it `String chosenWord = yourArray.remove(idx);`

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a list of words in some text file
2. Load that text file into your program
3. Shuffle that list
4. Use each one in order

(3) is the only step that needs thought: use `java.util.Collections#shuffle`

Answer (score 0):

Your best option here would be to create a list of words. Next you will randomly pick words from this list for your students to type.